# T-SQL DENY EXECUTE

Tags: sql, t-sql

what is the t-sql command/syntax to deny execute permissions to EVERYONE except the dbo on stored procedures? I want to grant execute to roles and users will then inherit rights based on the roles they belong to. as such i want new users to be denied execute on all the stored procedures i create.

thanks

sorry - i should mention i did this for a database already. i'm trying to create the db again but seem to have forgotten the code on how i did it.

i thought it was sonmethign like "deny execute to all"?

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly deny them permissions to these objects, adding them to a role which can execute them will not work - DENY has precedence.
By default no user has permissions to execute a stored procedure - the permission must be explicitly granted to either the user or the role they belong to. Do you really need more than just the default?

Comment: the grant will be given to the roles.
i just need to have the fault to be denied execute.
everything is via stored procedures and security is based on access via roles
currently, if i drop a stored procedure and re-create it(instead of alter), even as dbo, i cant execute it unless i assign it to a role and grant execute via the role.
on the new db, it doesnt seem to be workingt he same.

Comment: An explicit DENY will block them from executing the stored procedure regardless of the permissions of any role they belong to (unless they are also a db_owner). The default (ie no permissions set) will not allow them to execute the stored procedures.